# Installing local react library in another react app

Tags: reactjs

I created a react library project and used `rollup` to build it.  In `package.json`, I added the build script as follows:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c --bundleConfigAsCjs"
}
```

I also moved the `react` and `react-dom` under `peerDependencies` as follows:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": ...
    "react-dom": ...
}
```

Here is a snippet in `rollup.config.js`:

```
export default [
    {
        ...
        plugins: [
            peerDepsExternal().
            ...
        ]
        external: ["react", "react-dom"]
    }
...
```

First, in the react library project's root, I run `npm link`.
Second, in my other react project, I run `npm link myreactlibraryproj`

I see my `myreactlibraryproj` inside the node_modules exactly as is, including the `node_modules` directory.  So when I run my react project, I got `Cannot read properties of null (reading ''useState') on mhy react package`.  Based on the console log, it's complaining that there could be 2 react versions running.  So I thought of removing the `node_modules` directory from `node_modules/myreactlibraryproj` and suddenly it works.

When we usually npm install a package, usually in the `node_modules`, the installed package does not include the src folder and its own node_modules.  But since I do `npm link`, it seems to copy everything including the src and node_modules of my library.  How to exclude them?  Cause right now, I have to manually delete my library's node_modules for my other react app to work.